# Xcode - Swift Compiler Error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Double' to type 'Double'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

**How to convert a label outlet string to a double in swift?**

I have a timer which is updating the label: labelOutletForSecondsCount.text. The label is initialised with a String "0,00". I than wanted to save the stopped timeString (I'm getting from my timer) as a Double in a variable to use it in some calculation.

I thought that this line of code should do it but I get the following "Swift Compiler Error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Double' to type 'Double'".

```
var timeStringIntoDoubleValue = (labelOutletForSecondsCount.text as NSString).doubleValue
```

It worked fine with this line of code:

```
var textFieldInsertLengthIntoDoubleValue = (textFieldInsertLength.text as NSString).doubleValue
```

But why is it not working with the labelOutletForSecondsCount.text?

I should mention that I'm doing this in computed properties:

```
var length : Double {
    var textFieldInsertLengthIntoDoubleValue = (textFieldInsertLength.text as NSString).doubleValue
    return textFieldInsertLengthIntoDoubleValue
}

var time : Double {
    var timeStringIntoDoubleValue = (labelOutletForSecondsCount.text as NSString).doubleValue
    return timeStringIntoDoubleValue
}
```

This most likely adds to the strange error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Double' to type 'Double'.

Comment: I had troubles indenting my code blocks right. I'd be glad if someone could help me out. I didn't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The `text` property of `UILabel` is an optional:

```
var text: String? // default is nil
```

which can not be converted directly to `NSString`. You could forcefully unwrap the value:

```
var timeStringIntoDoubleValue = (labelOutletForSecondsCount.text! as NSString).doubleValue
```

but this would crash at runtime if the `text` value is `nil`. Better use
"optional binding":

```
var timeStringIntoDoubleValue = 0.0
if let text = labelOutletForSecondsCount.text {
    timeStringIntoDoubleValue = (text as NSString).doubleValue
}
```

Alternatively, use the ["nil-coalescing operator" `??`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123) to provide a default value:

```
var timeStringIntoDoubleValue = (labelOutletForSecondsCount.text ?? "0" as NSString).doubleValue
```

Here, `labelOutletForSecondsCount.text ?? "0"` evaluates to the (unwrapped) text
value if that is not `nil`, and to `"0"` otherwise.

---

The reason that it compiles with a text field is that the `text` property
of `UITextField` is declared as an *implicitly unwrapped* optional:

```
var text: String! // default is nil
```

Comment: var timeStringIntoDoubleValue = (labelOutletForSecondsCount.text ?? "0,00" as NSString).doubleValue

Comment: @Gabriel: "0" works as well, and I prefer it because it is not locale dependent (whether comma or period is used as separator).